# Multi stage search views

Tags: views

I'm building a website that needs the following functionality -

So two different content types - work type profile and job type.

So work type profile contains a field 'Skillset A' and a 'Skillset B' so I can create this content type and select the different skills the type has.

Job type has lots of different detail about the job, like salary etc.

I want a user to be able to select their work type as stage one, and then select the salary level they require for the the second stage filter.

Then I want a list of jobs to appear that they can do based on the skills within their salary range (so the jobs that match their skillset profile)

And I want the jobs to then be further filterable by the skillset. So they can see all the jobs that match the skillset.

How would I configure something like this with views?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would see how these projects approached this popular scenario & go from there as opposed to starting from scratch:

https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter
https://www.drupal.org/project/drop_jobs

[edit]...So I decided to try both those out as I was thinking about simple data modeling and how to communicate it best. There's a demo linked on the recruiter distro but decided to use https://simplytest.me/ which is great in case you haven't heard of it.

The drop_jobs broke but the recruiter distro worked and it provides facets which is probably the way you should go too so people can just refine their search to their needs - the trouble with trying to do it in just views alone is you start with a big list of data and provide options from the boundaries you know, e.g. salary bracket, but if there's nothing in the one they choose then you'll end up with no results.

The benefit of using facets is by default it will only display the available facets, and you can have things like facet counts. You can display all the facets so you get things like $10k-$20k(0) if there aren't any, but at least the user doesn't have a fruitless search.

See http://dgo.to/facets

Comment: comment removed